# Symfony2 Saving selected date from form to the database as DateTime

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, datetime

In my form a user selects when he would like to get the the purchase simply like this:

```
        ->add('start_date', 'date', array(
            'input'  => 'datetime',
            'widget' => 'choice',
        ))
```

Now I would like to save this date to the database in this field:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="campaign_list_end_date", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $endDate;
```

So when the form is submited I get the date. But its an array of strings:

```
$data = $request->request->get('courier');
echo var_dump($data['start_date']); die;

array (size=3)
  'month' => string '2' (length=1)
  'day' => string '1' (length=1)
  'year' => string '2012' (length=4)
```

How can I convert this value to a DateTime object?

I tried something like this, it didnt work:

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$start_date = $date->setTimestamp($data['start_date']);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When using symfony forms, you should retrieve the posted data from the form itself. The form will transform the data to the correct type for you:

```
$date = $form->get('start_date')->getData();
```

in addition, if your form is bound to an entity, you can also get the bound entity with the posted values extracted into it:

```
$entity = $form->getData();
```

Comment: I am trying to acces the forms data in a dfferent form. I am using Javascript to submit the form and I receive the data prof POST Request in a different controller.

Comment: Then you just need to build the same form in that different controller too, so it can handle the data.